# Why my android application not working after uploading on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have developed an android social chatting application it's working fine when test in my emulator and real device. But when i uploaded that application to Google console i mean Google play Store it's not working just crushed.
Please help me

one more thing i think my code are getting chenged after uploadig to googleplay.

```
2021-06-25 10:07:00.017 1531-1618/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isBiometricDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:07:00.020 1531-1618/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isBiometricDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:07:00.736 1531-1618/? E/ColorZoomWindowManagerService: onConfigurationChanged rotation not changed - prevRotation: 0
2021-06-25 10:07:00.743 1531-1618/? E/ColorZoomWindowManagerService: onConfigurationChanged rotation not changed - prevRotation: 0
2021-06-25 10:07:00.903 1531-1782/? E/ORMS_CORE: Unsupported action!!!
2021-06-25 10:07:00.946 1531-4555/? E/ORMS_Platform : OplusResourceManagerPlatformUtils: readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:07:00.974 1531-4555/? E/ORMS_Platform : OplusResourceManagerPlatformUtils: readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:07:01.270 25513-25513/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManager: sInstance is null, start a new sInstance
2021-06-25 10:07:04.379 25513-25513/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: artix.development.easysent, PID: 25513
    d.d.b.r.d: No properties to serialize found on class c.a.a.u.a
        at d.d.b.r.y.z0.o.a$a.<init>(:11)
        at d.d.b.r.y.z0.o.a.e(Unknown Source:12)
        at d.d.b.r.y.z0.o.a.b(:4)
        at artix.development.easysent.HomeActivity$b.i(:6)
        at d.d.b.r.y.s0.d(:2)
        at d.d.b.r.y.a1.d.a(Unknown Source:2)
        at d.d.b.r.y.a1.h.run(:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8194)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
2021-06-25 10:07:05.121 1531-4221/? E/ORMS_Platform : OplusResourceManagerPlatformUtils: readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:07:05.136 1531-4221/? E/ORMS_Platform : OplusResourceManagerPlatformUtils: readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:07:47.272 1531-2016/? E/ColorZoomWindowManagerService: onConfigurationChanged rotation not changed - prevRotation: 0
2021-06-25 10:07:47.276 1531-2016/? E/ColorZoomWindowManagerService: onConfigurationChanged rotation not changed - prevRotation: 0
2021-06-25 10:07:47.386 1531-2512/? E/ORMS_Platform : OplusResourceManagerPlatformUtils: readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:07:47.399 1531-1782/? E/ORMS_CORE: Unsupported action!!!
2021-06-25 10:07:47.424 1531-2827/? E/ORMS_Platform : OplusResourceManagerPlatformUtils: readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:07:47.429 25600-25600/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManager: sInstance is null, start a new sInstance
2021-06-25 10:07:50.285 25600-25600/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: artix.development.easysent, PID: 25600
    d.d.b.r.d: No properties to serialize found on class c.a.a.u.a
        at d.d.b.r.y.z0.o.a$a.<init>(:11)
        at d.d.b.r.y.z0.o.a.e(Unknown Source:12)
        at d.d.b.r.y.z0.o.a.b(:4)
        at artix.development.easysent.HomeActivity$b.i(:6)
        at d.d.b.r.y.s0.d(:2)
        at d.d.b.r.y.a1.d.a(Unknown Source:2)
        at d.d.b.r.y.a1.h.run(:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8194)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
2021-06-25 10:07:51.178 1531-4221/? E/ORMS_Platform : OplusResourceManagerPlatformUtils: readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:07:51.198 1531-2827/? E/ORMS_Platform : OplusResourceManagerPlatformUtils: readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:07:52.609 1531-1587/? E/OplusDisplayPowerControllerFeature: execute mBlockReasonList.clear
2021-06-25 10:07:52.745 1531-1688/? E/OppoStorageManagerFeature: onMessageDPolicyExpect failed!
    java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /sys/fs/f2fs
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:434)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
        at com.android.server.storage.OppoStorageManagerFeature.onMessageDPolicyExpect(OppoStorageManagerFeature.java:876)
        at com.android.server.storage.OppoStorageManagerFeature.onStorageManagerMessageHandle(OppoStorageManagerFeature.java:515)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService$StorageManagerServiceHandler.handleMessage(StorageManagerService.java:743)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2021-06-25 10:07:52.894 1531-1577/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:07:52.894 1531-1577/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:07:53.110 1531-1577/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:07:53.111 1531-1577/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:07:59.555 1531-1587/? E/OplusDisplayPowerControllerFeature: execute mBlockReasonList.clear
2021-06-25 10:07:59.696 1531-1688/? E/OppoStorageManagerFeature: onMessageDPolicyExpect failed!
    java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /sys/fs/f2fs
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:434)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
        at com.android.server.storage.OppoStorageManagerFeature.onMessageDPolicyExpect(OppoStorageManagerFeature.java:876)
        at com.android.server.storage.OppoStorageManagerFeature.onStorageManagerMessageHandle(OppoStorageManagerFeature.java:515)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService$StorageManagerServiceHandler.handleMessage(StorageManagerService.java:743)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2021-06-25 10:08:00.167 1531-4557/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isBiometricDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:08:00.169 1531-1546/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isBiometricDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:08:01.469 1531-4552/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:08:01.683 1531-2907/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:08:01.686 1531-4557/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:08:01.689 1531-2907/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:08:01.714 1531-1617/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:08:01.718 1531-1617/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:08:01.719 1531-1617/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:08:01.723 1531-1617/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:08:01.739 1531-2512/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:08:01.752 1531-1617/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:09:00.043 1531-2907/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isBiometricDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:09:00.045 1531-1618/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isBiometricDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:09:28.166 1531-1577/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:09:28.167 1531-1577/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:09:28.242 1531-1587/? E/OplusDisplayPowerControllerFeature: execute mBlockReasonList.clear
2021-06-25 10:09:28.307 1531-1688/? E/OppoStorageManagerFeature: onMessageDPolicyExpect failed!
    java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /sys/fs/f2fs
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:434)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
        at com.android.server.storage.OppoStorageManagerFeature.onMessageDPolicyExpect(OppoStorageManagerFeature.java:876)
        at com.android.server.storage.OppoStorageManagerFeature.onStorageManagerMessageHandle(OppoStorageManagerFeature.java:515)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService$StorageManagerServiceHandler.handleMessage(StorageManagerService.java:743)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2021-06-25 10:09:28.358 1531-1577/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:09:28.358 1531-1577/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:09:31.489 1531-1587/? E/OplusDisplayPowerControllerFeature: execute mBlockReasonList.clear
2021-06-25 10:09:31.567 1531-1688/? E/OppoStorageManagerFeature: onMessageDPolicyExpect failed!
    java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /sys/fs/f2fs
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:434)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
        at com.android.server.storage.OppoStorageManagerFeature.onMessageDPolicyExpect(OppoStorageManagerFeature.java:876)
        at com.android.server.storage.OppoStorageManagerFeature.onStorageManagerMessageHandle(OppoStorageManagerFeature.java:515)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService$StorageManagerServiceHandler.handleMessage(StorageManagerService.java:743)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2021-06-25 10:09:32.895 1531-1617/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:09:32.943 1531-2512/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:09:32.945 1531-1618/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:09:32.948 1531-1617/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:09:32.967 1531-1617/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:09:32.969 1531-1618/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:09:32.970 1531-1617/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:09:32.972 1531-1618/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:09:32.981 1531-1618/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:09:32.987 1531-1618/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isUSBFileTransferDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:10:00.017 1531-2827/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isBiometricDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:10:00.018 1531-2507/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isBiometricDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:10:04.751 1531-2827/? E/ColorZoomWindowManagerService: onConfigurationChanged rotation not changed - prevRotation: 0
2021-06-25 10:10:04.754 1531-2827/? E/ColorZoomWindowManagerService: onConfigurationChanged rotation not changed - prevRotation: 0
2021-06-25 10:10:04.871 1531-2507/? E/ORMS_Platform : OplusResourceManagerPlatformUtils: readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:10:04.889 1531-4076/? E/ORMS_Platform : OplusResourceManagerPlatformUtils: readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:10:04.917 1531-1782/? E/ORMS_CORE: Unsupported action!!!
2021-06-25 10:10:04.937 25705-25705/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManager: sInstance is null, start a new sInstance
2021-06-25 10:10:07.432 25705-25705/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: artix.development.easysent, PID: 25705
    d.d.b.r.d: No properties to serialize found on class c.a.a.u.a
        at d.d.b.r.y.z0.o.a$a.<init>(:11)
        at d.d.b.r.y.z0.o.a.e(Unknown Source:12)
        at d.d.b.r.y.z0.o.a.b(:4)
        at artix.development.easysent.HomeActivity$b.i(:6)
        at d.d.b.r.y.s0.d(:2)
        at d.d.b.r.y.a1.d.a(Unknown Source:2)
        at d.d.b.r.y.a1.h.run(:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8194)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:632)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
2021-06-25 10:10:08.207 1531-1617/? E/ORMS_Platform : OplusResourceManagerPlatformUtils: readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:10:08.221 1531-2507/? E/ORMS_Platform : OplusResourceManagerPlatformUtils: readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:11:00.032 1531-4552/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isBiometricDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:11:00.035 1531-2016/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isBiometricDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:12:00.016 1531-4552/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isBiometricDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:12:00.018 1531-4221/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isBiometricDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:12:18.162 1531-1577/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:12:18.163 1531-1577/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:13:00.029 1531-1617/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isBiometricDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:13:00.032 1531-1618/? E/OplusCustomizeRestrictionManagerService: isBiometricDisabled start
2021-06-25 10:13:08.128 1531-1577/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:13:08.129 1531-1577/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:13:08.293 1531-1587/? E/OplusDisplayPowerControllerFeature: execute mBlockReasonList.clear
2021-06-25 10:13:08.371 1531-1688/? E/OppoStorageManagerFeature: onMessageDPolicyExpect failed!
    java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /sys/fs/f2fs
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:434)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
        at com.android.server.storage.OppoStorageManagerFeature.onMessageDPolicyExpect(OppoStorageManagerFeature.java:876)
        at com.android.server.storage.OppoStorageManagerFeature.onStorageManagerMessageHandle(OppoStorageManagerFeature.java:515)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService$StorageManagerServiceHandler.handleMessage(StorageManagerService.java:743)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2021-06-25 10:13:08.458 1531-1577/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:13:08.458 1531-1577/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2021-06-25 10:13:10.361 1531-1587/? E/OplusDisplayPowerControllerFeature: execute mBlockReasonList.clear
2021-06-25 10:13:10.444 1531-1688/? E/OppoStorageManagerFeature: onMessageDPolicyExpect failed!
    java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /sys/fs/f2fs
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:434)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
        at com.android.server.storage.OppoStorageManagerFeature.onMessageDPolicyExpect(OppoStorageManagerFeature.java:876)
        at com.android.server.storage.OppoStorageManagerFeature.onStorageManagerMessageHandle(OppoStorageManagerFeature.java:515)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService$StorageManagerServiceHandler.handleMessage(StorageManagerService.java:743)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:255)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Comment: Please provide a more detailed explanation of the specific problem, along with the crash logs.

Comment: Without any code or errors this is obviously impossible to solve. An app crash could be down to an infinite number of reasons. You're asking us to look for a needle in a haystack, without even providing the haystack.

Comment: now i have uploaded the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  you have enable minifyEnabled to true without adding ProGuard rules that's creating crash. Quick Fix disable minifyEnabled to false.

```
release {
        minifyEnabled false
        ...
    }
```

then have a look on useful links : https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/practical-proguard-rules-examples-5640a3907dc9